# How to drop records based on number of unique days using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-05 12:59:00','2173-05-04 13:14:00','2173-05-05 13:37:00','2173-07-03 13:39:00','2173-07-04 11:30:00','2173-04-04 16:00:00','2173-04-09 22:00:00','2173-04-11 04:00:00','2173- 04-13 04:30:00','2173-04-14 08:00:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,5,5,1,6,5,5,8,3,4,6]})
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['time_1'].dt.month
```

What I would like to do is drop records/subjects who doesn't have more than `4 or more` unique days

If you see my sample dataframe, you can see that `subject_id = 1` has only 3 unique dates which is `3,4 and 5` so I would like to drop `subject_id = 1` completely. But if you see `subject_id = 2` he has more than 4 unique dates like `4,9,11,13,14`. Please note that date values has timestamp, hence I extract the day from each datetime field and check for unique records.

This is what I tried

```
df.groupby(['subject_id','day']).transform('size')>4 # doesn't work
df[df.groupby(['subject_id','day'])['subject_id'].transform('size')>=4] # doesn't produce expected output
```

I expect my output to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function from `size` to [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html), grouping only by the `subject_id` column:

```
df = df[df.groupby('subject_id')['day'].transform('nunique')>=4]
```

Or alternatively you can use [filtration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration), but this should be slower if you're using a larger dataframe or many unique groups:

```
df = df.groupby('subject_id').filter(lambda x: x['day'].nunique()>=4)
```

---

```
print (df)
    subject_id              time_1  val  day  month
7            2 2173-04-04 16:00:00    5    4      4
8            2 2173-04-09 22:00:00    8    9      4
9            2 2173-04-11 04:00:00    3   11      4
10           2 2173-04-13 04:30:00    4   13      4
11           2 2173-04-14 08:00:00    6   14      4
```